# Desejo fazer um grafico interativo, porém não estou conseguindo

Tags: python, gráfico

Desejo fazer um grafico em python ,utilizando o mathplotlib, onde seja possivel mover os pontos livrimente, no meu caso só consigo mexer um. Alguém pode me ajudar quanto a isso?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# cria os pontos iniciais

x = [0, 90,30]
y = [0, 30,40]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

# cria o gráfico de setor
wedge = ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Wedge(
        (0, 0),         # (x,y)
        100,            # radius
        0,             # theta1 (in degrees)
        45,            # theta2
        color="g", alpha=0.2
    )
)

# cria o gráfico de setor
wedge1 = ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Wedge(
        (1, 30),         # (x,y)
        100,            # radius
        120,             # theta1 (in degrees)
        180,            # theta2
        color="b", alpha=0.2
    )
)

wedge2 = ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Wedge(
        (30, 40),         # (x,y)
        100,            # radius
        120,             # theta1 (in degrees)
        180,            # theta2
        color="g", alpha=0.2
    )
)


def on_move(event):
    if not event.inaxes: #Verifica se o mouse está sobre o objeto do eixo e se o botão esquerdo do mouse está precionado.
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    index = scatter.get_paths()[0].contains_point((x, y))

    if index == 0:
        scatter.set_offsets([(x, y), scatter.get_offsets()[1]])
    elif index == 1:
        scatter.set_offsets([scatter.get_offsets()[0], (x, y)])
    wedge_center = (x, y)
    
    wedge.set_center(wedge_center)
    fig1.canvas.draw()


cid = fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)




# cria o gráfico de dispersão
scatter = ax1.scatter(x, y)
plt.axis([-150, 150, 0, 250])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Para mover vários pontos em um gráfico com o **matplotlib**, você precisa modificar o código para criar um **conjunto de pontos** em vez de um único ponto. Isso pode ser feito criando um objeto **Scatter**, em vez de um objeto **Patch**, como mostrado no código **exemplo** abaixo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# cria os pontos iniciais
x = [0, 90, 30]
y = [0, 30, 40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# cria o gráfico de dispersão
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y)

def on_move(event):
    if not event.inaxes: #Verifica se o mouse está sobre o objeto do eixo e se o botão esquerdo do mouse está precionado.
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    scatter.set_offsets([(x, y), scatter.get_offsets()[1], scatter.get_offsets()[2]])
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

O código acima cria um gráfico de dispersão com os pontos iniciais e define uma função on_move para manipular a posição dos pontos. A função verifica se o mouse está sobre o objeto do eixo e se o botão esquerdo do mouse está pressionado. Em seguida, atualiza a posição dos pontos usando o método set_offsets do objeto scatter. Finalmente, o método **canvas.draw()** é chamado para atualizar o gráfico com a nova posição dos pontos.

---

**EDITADO:**

**REPLICA ADICIONADA PELO AUTOR:**

> Porém, por algum motivo, está aparecendo os três pontos, mas só é
> possível mover um, até se o mouse estiver sobre o outro. Estou
> utlizando o Microsolft Visual Studio Code, no spyder nem é possível
> mexer, fica tudo estatico

**RESPOSTA:**

O problema pode estar relacionado com o backend que o **Matplotlib** está utilizando no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento. Alguns backends, como o **Qt**, permitem interações de mouse mais complexas, enquanto outros, como o **TkAgg** (que é o padrão no **Matplotlib**), possuem algumas limitações.

Uma possível solução para permitir a movimentação de todos os pontos é utilizar o backend "**Qt5Agg**" do **Matplotlib**. Para fazer isso, você precisa definir a variável de ambiente "**MPLBACKEND**" antes de importar o **Matplotlib**. No Visual Studio Code, você pode fazer isso adicionando a seguinte linha no início do seu código:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLBACKEND'] = 'Qt5Agg'
```

Em seguida, execute o seu código normalmente e verifique se agora é possível mover todos os pontos. Se isso não funcionar, você pode tentar outras opções de backend, como "**TkAgg**", "**WXAgg**" ou "**GTKAgg**", dependendo da disponibilidade na sua máquina.

Note que ao utilizar um backend diferente do padrão, pode ser necessário instalar dependências adicionais e configurar o ambiente corretamente. Verifique a documentação do **Matplotlib** para obter mais informações sobre como configurar os backends.

Segue abaixo um **exemplo** completo que utiliza o backend "**Qt5Agg**" e permite a movimentação de vários pontos em um gráfico de dispersão:

```
import os
os.environ['MPLBACKEND'] = 'Qt5Agg'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# cria os pontos iniciais
x = [0, 90, 30]
y = [0, 30, 40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# cria o gráfico de dispersão
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y)

def on_move(event):
    if not event.inaxes: #Verifica se o mouse está sobre o objeto do eixo e se o botão esquerdo do mouse está precionado.
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    offsets = scatter.get_offsets()
    index = event.ind[0]
    offsets[index] = (x, y)
    scatter.set_offsets(offsets)
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

Neste **exemplo**, as alterações em relação ao código original são a inclusão da linha o`s.environ['MPLBACKEND'] = 'Qt5Agg'` para definir o backend a ser utilizado, e a modificação da função on_move para permitir a movimentação de todos os pontos.

Na função **on_move**, a variável index é utilizada para determinar qual ponto deve ser movido com base no índice retornado pelo evento `event.ind`. Em seguida, os deslocamentos (**offsets**) são atualizados e o método **set_offsets** é chamado para atualizar a posição de todos os pontos no gráfico.

Espero que este **exemplo** ajude! Lembre-se de verificar se o backend escolhido está instalado corretamente em sua máquina.

**E para melhor entender**, segue abaixo um **outro exemplo** completo que utiliza o backend "**TkAgg**" e permite a movimentação de vários pontos em um gráfico de dispersão:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# cria os pontos iniciais
x = [0, 90, 30]
y = [0, 30, 40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# cria o gráfico de dispersão
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y)

def on_move(event):
    if not event.inaxes: #Verifica se o mouse está sobre o objeto do eixo e se o botão esquerdo do mouse está precionado.
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    offsets = scatter.get_offsets()
    index = event.ind[0]
    offsets[index] = (x, y)
    scatter.set_offsets(offsets)
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

Neste **outro exemplo**, as alterações em relação ao código original são a inclusão da linha `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` para definir o **backend** a ser utilizado, e a modificação da função **on_move** para permitir a movimentação de todos os pontos.

Na função **on_move**, a variável **index** é utilizada para determinar qual ponto deve ser movido com base no índice retornado pelo evento **event.ind**. Em seguida, os deslocamentos (**offsets**) são atualizados e o método **set_offsets** é chamado para atualizar a posição de todos os pontos no gráfico.

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado por sua resposta. Porém, por algum motivo, está aparecendo os três pontos, mas só é possível mover um, até se o mouse estiver sobre o outro. Estou utlizando o Microsolft Visual Studio Code, no spyder nem é possível mexer, fica tudo estatico.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Eu editei minha resposta adicionando uma possivel solução!

Comment: Inclui uma nova alteração na resposta adicionando um codigo exemplo com a implementação. Melhor, com dois exemplos, um para cada backend!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua atenção. Porém o mesmo erro pesiste, mesmo alterando os backends. Gostaria de saber qual a platarforma que o senhor usa para executar os arquivos?